# Golang JSON config for routes

Tags: json, go, routes, mux, gorilla

I have been trying to setup a JSON config file to setup dynamic routes for my application. The idea is that I will be able to setup my own URL structure depending on who is using the service. I have a struct that takes in JSON and that works fine. I am using gorilla mux.

```
 type CustomRoute struct {
    Name string
    Method string
    Path string
    HandleFunc string
 }
```

The JSON is basically identical to the struct and it goes in fine.

The issue I have is getting the HandleFunc section.

Here is the code:

```
func NewRouter() *mux.Router {

routerInstance := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)

    /*
    All routes from the routing table
    */

    // r = []CustomRoute with the JSON data 
    r := loadRoute()
    for _, route := range r {
       var handler http.Handler

       handler = route.HandlerFunc
       handler = core.Logger(handler, route.Name)

       routerInstance.
           Methods(route.Method).
           Path(route.Path).
           Name(route.Name).
           Handler(handler)

    }

    return routerInstance
}
```

I always get the following error (as one would expect)

> cannot use route.HandlerFunc (type string) as type http.Handler in assignment:
>           string does not implement http.Handler (missing ServeHTTP method)

I was told to use something like:

```
var functions = map[string]interface{}{
    "HandleFunc1": HandleFunc1,
}
```

But I have no idea how to make this work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [RayenWindspear](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1276480/rayfenwindspear) I was able to fix the problem. It was very simple (like everything). The map code should look like this:

```
var functions = map[string]http.HandlerFunc{
    "HandleFunc1": HandleFunc1,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using a mux for subdomains, so my examples may be a bit off. The map you are being told to use is done something like this:

```
type Handlers map[string]http.HandlerFunc

func (handlers Handlers) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    path := r.URL.Path
    if handle := handlers[path]; handle != nil {
        handle.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    } else {
        http.Error(w, "Not found", 404)
    }
}
```

Comment: You got me over the line thank you. I have to change my map to:

var functions = map[string]http.HandlerFunc

Comment: I figured something would be off. Like I said, mine was specific to subdomains, hence the map of handlers. I actually modified the first line in the function from looking up the subdomain, to getting the path, so my code here probably doesn't even work as is :O. I'll edit it to use handleFuncs